# Convert query to single row query - Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

My query `select apex_string.format('%s  %s',empno,rpad(ename,5,' ')) as out from emp;`

return below result 3 rows.

```
7839  KING 
7698  BLAKE
7782  CLARK
```

Is it possible get result as single row some like this:

7839  KING

7698  BLAKE

7782  CLARK

Note: After **7839  KING** new row in html that is **< br / >** tag...Is it possible in oracle sql query define new row?

Maybe all convert in clob? Result I want to export in TXT file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Listagg` with `chr(10)` (a line feed character), perhaps?

```
SQL> select listagg(empno ||' '|| rpad(ename, 7, ' '), chr(10)) within group (order by empno) as out
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno = 10;

OUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7782 CLARK
7839 KING
7934 MILLER


SQL>
```